# Windows 10: Incomplete Display Of A Font's Characters

Tags: windows-10, fonts, unicode

- by default, windows 10 comes with the **segoe ui emoji** font
- this font is the only default font that has the following 4 unicode characters:

  - (x1f6f7)
  - (x1f6f8)
  - (x1f6f9)
  - (x1f6fa)
- and i haven't installed any additional fonts that have any of those characters

- if:

  - an app or the windows desktop uses this font
- then:

  - the app or windows desktop should be able to display all 4 of those characters
- in contrast, if:

  - an app or the windows desktop does **not** use this font
- then:

  - the app or windows desktop should **not** be able to display any of those 4 characters
- however, this isn't what i experience

- **run dialog**, **notepad**, and **ultra edit**, will each display:

  - (x1f6f7)
  - (x1f6f8)
- but they won't display:

  - (x1f6f9)
  - (x1f6fa)
- in contrast, **windows search bar** will display **all 4 of the characters**

- here's a 1 minute video demonstration and some images:

  - https://www.dropbox.com/s/pvxahxd3y2d3qjt/1~win~unicode~transport~block~bug.mp4

[image: image 1]
 [image: image 2]
 [image: image 3]
 [image: image 4]

- on a side note, i'm using a recently updated, stable version of windows 10:

  - build 18362.535 (1903/May 2019 Update)

**? what's the cause of this bizarre behavior**

**† edit: update: 2019 dec 18**

- **@harrymc**

  - "do not expect pasting these characters to work when the current font is not Segoe UI Emoji, unless one or more of them happens to be included in the current font"
- **me**

  - this is precisely the bizarre behavior
  - many apps have a **font fallback system**
  - however, **segoe ui emoji** is the **only** font of mine that has these 4 char
  - yet, under a different font, 2 of these char still display
  - this would suggest that a font fallback to **segoe ui emoji** has occurred
  - but despite this apparent font fallback, the other 2 char still don't display

Comment: I don't get the same results : As long as the font is defined as Segoe UI Emoji, all four characters are there : https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLTpx.jpg. For Windows dialogs: You cannot force them to use another font than the one they are programmed with (not without hacking the `.exe`).

Comment: I'm suggesting that this feature you are seeing "font fallback" is a WPF feature that doesn't work on old WinForms textbox elements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@harrymc
"All software under Windows uses the same API which is supported by the same Windows components."

me:
* this is relative to your definition of "api"
* they both run in .net, which itself runs in winrt (windows runtime)
* however, they can still have different interfaces
* with this noted, wiki suggests that they're different:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms
* "Windows Forms is built on the existing Windows API and some controls merely wrap underlying Windows components."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation
* "The architecture of WPF spans both managed code and native code components.
However, the public API exposed is only available via managed code.
While the majority of WPF is in managed code, the composition engine which renders the WPF applications is a native component."

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.fontfamily?view=netframework-4.8

"The WPF font fallback mechanism replaces previous Win32 font substitution technologies."

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3083806/why-does-some-text-display-with-square-boxes-in-some-apps-on-windows-1

"Windows still has great support for Unicode and for international text, and ensuring that universal Windows apps can have great text display on desktop devices and every other form factor

@HackSlash
"The run dialog and notepad are both ancient legacy elements that don't get updated with the rest of the OS."

me:
* not true
* however, notepad doesn't get updated as frequently as wordpad

- the 4 emojis that i mentioned were added 1 at a time to windows:

  - https://emojipedia.org/microsoft/windows-10-fall-creators-update/sled/
  - https://emojipedia.org/microsoft/windows-10-fall-creators-update/flying-saucer/
  - https://emojipedia.org/microsoft/windows-10-october-2018-update/skateboard/
  - https://emojipedia.org/microsoft/windows-10-may-2019-update/auto-rickshaw/
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list

  - this list segoe ui emoji as 1.27
  - but mine is 1.29
- the evidence suggests that windows updated some of their software (wordpap, windows search) to reference the newest version of segoe ui emoji during font fallback
- whereas, other software (notepad, run dialog box) references an older version of segoe ui emoji

**note**
* i'll tidy up this post soon
* i just barely had time to make this before the bounty time ran out
* @harrymc and @HackSlash both had fundamental wrongs
* so i wanted to provide more accurate info

Comment: No, I didn't have anything "fundamental wrong". Both of you have serious misunderstandings of the font engine. Even if your own text says "the composition engine which renders the WPF applications is a native component". Both of you think that new higher-level API doesn't use the lower-level, and that the fonts engine is nothing to rewrite, this enormous engine that can convert every character in every language and font to glyph and mix them in the directions of left, right and bottom, including equations. Unfortunately you convinced the poster of the old/new software concept, untrue as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Modern UI elements do not work the same way as legacy elements. The run dialog and notepad are both ancient legacy elements that don't get updated with the rest of the OS. The search bar is a modern OS element so this should be the behavior of all newer elements of the OS. The Segoe family of fonts were developed for modern UI and they are all used for various text display functions. That being said, Microsoft development is not known for consistency. You might find different elements, developed by different teams, that have different behavior.

For more information about how fonts are handled differently in "Modern" Windows 10 applications read this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/typography-in-wpf

> WPF provides enhanced font support by providing the following features: Unicode for all text. Font behavior and selection no longer require charset or codepage.

This explains how modern apps can display characters from multiple fonts within a font family.

Answer (score -2):

I disagree with the accepted answer : All software under Windows uses the same
API which is supported by the same Windows components.
While older software may use outdated API, this is not the case with either
Notepad or Wordpad, which are still under development today.

The problem experienced by the poster with Notepad and Wordpad relates more
to user interface than a problem with those products, and here is the proof,
where the characters are correctly displayed when the current font is specified
as Segoe UI Emoji:

[image]

However, do not expect pasting these characters to work when the current font
is not Segoe UI Emoji, unless one or more of them happens to be included in
the current font.

For Windows dialogs: When the dialog is created, the font used by text field
is specified in the dialog's definition.
The Segoe UI Emoji font is obviously unsuitable as a regular text font
and so would never be used for such user interface.

You cannot force a dialog to use another font than the one it is programmed with,
at least not without hacking the `.exe` or `.dll` that contains the definition
of the dialog. So you cannot expect that pasting emojis would work in dialogs.

**EDIT**

Unicode character range, although very large, is not enough to contain all
the characters of all the languages on Earth. This is why fonts are important,
since the same Unicode code-point can be used for different characters
in different fonts.

The Windows clipboard is rich, unlike the Linux clipboard. It does not
only contain the characters, but can also contain information about the
language, direction (right, left), font and more. The API is capable
of setting and getting different formats, and is also intelligent enough
to convert upon getting the stored format to the requested format.

So what you get when you copy and paste special characters,
depends on the API that was used by the source and target programs.
Below is an example that uses Wordpad.

The is the initial text in the Arial font:

[image]

Now I copy-paste your fourth character from the browser to the end of the text,
and behold the miracle - the font is now Segoe UI Emoji:

[image]

So now I click on the word "Arial" and the font is all of a sudden different:

[image]

So we now have text which is in two different fonts. The character we pasted
in () is a Unicode character, but this same character can be represented
differently in different fonts. You can already see that in Wordpad by changing
the font of this character from Segoe UI Emoji to another one and seeing
its representation change. I repeat : **Its Unicode code-point stays the
same, it is only its display that changes to fit the font**.

So where did the font information come from? Answer: From the clipboard,
where the browser was clever enough to stash all the relevant information.
If the copy program and the paste program are sophisticated enough,
the pasted character will always keep its font and always be correctly
displayed.

Every program that uses Windows rich text fields will display the character
correctly with its font, for example Wordpad.

Programs that use mono-font fields will display the character as
represented in the specified font.
If the character has no representation in that font, it will most often be
represented as a square. For example, Notepad.

As mentioned above, dialogs have their font hard-coded into the definition
of the dialog, and that font is highly unlikely to be Segoe UI Emoji.

Comment: There are two very distinct Windows GUI APIs in use today: The old WinForms, and the newer WPF. "Modern" apps use WPF. They look, feel, and behave differently than WinForms while providing similar functionality. The default font for Notepad is "Consolas" where the default font for legacy elements is either "Tahoma" or "MS Sans Serif". Modern elements use the "Segoe" font family by default. You are also wrong about changing the system font. Of course you can, this is how language support functions.

Comment: @HackSlash: I don't understand your remark. Do you think that WPF doesn't use Windows DLLs and that it rewrote the kernel? I don't get it. I think you do not know font support software and how complicated it is. Windows only has one underlying engine after all the APIs are done calling each other.

Comment: You don't need to rewrite the kernel to display fonts. WPF does have new *"new text application programming interfaces (APIs)."* as cited in this article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/typography-in-wpf

Comment: There is an important bit of information in that relevant article: *"Unicode for all text. Font behavior and selection no longer require charset or codepage."*

Comment: @HackSlash: Charset/codepage belong to the pre-Unicode era. The current font engine is full Unicode in Windows since many years ago. You're mixing things up. I suggest you delete your remarks and undo the downvote.

Comment: Did you read the MS article? It's talking about how fonts are handled differently in WPF. Yes, charset/codepage belong to the pre-Unicode era just like WinForms and all the legacy elements of Windows 10 still kicking around like the "Run Dialog". Notepad is a WinForms app and so is the run dialog cited by OP. I think you're mixing things up and should do some more research before telling me what to do. If you have a source for your information, feel free to cite the source. Otherwise, I think the link I posted speaks for itself.

Comment: @HackSlash: You depend on articles. I have worked on the software. You are very wrong, but there is no point in continuing the discussion.

Comment: @harrmc Yes, I depend upon articles written by Microsoft for developers because I'm a Windows developer. If you don't want to RTFM then you are correct, there is no point in continuing the discussion. If you don't know what WPF is you should look it up. The single most important difference between WinForms and WPF is the fact that WinForms is simply a layer on top of the standard Windows controls (e.g. a TextBox), WPF is built from scratch and doesn't rely on standard Windows controls. You will definitely notice if you have ever worked with a framework that depends on Win32/WinAPI.

Comment: @HackSlash: I don't care about Windows controls. This is about the font engine. Really.

Comment: And you were talking about how there is only one WinAPI... Needing kernel hacks to change fonts... Really.

Comment: @HackSlash: You have apparently always worked with upper-level API, never calling directly Windows DLLs in the font engine. This discussion is too much for me. I'm out of here.

Comment: @harrymc * i added a response to you at the end of my main post

Comment: @abcjme: I added an explanation of this apparent font fallback, of what really happens in Windows. I just cannot leave uncorrected the answer that you accepted, answer which is based on misunderstanding.

Comment: It's incredible how some people won't accept facts.

Comment: @harrymc You're the one calling your opinions "facts". Both abcjme and me posted links to back up our facts. You just spouted opinion based on questionable experience. Walk back your combative stance and take a good look at your glass house before you throw those stones.

Comment: @HackSlash: I proved my facts empirically, not via links whose contents you misunderstood.